# How can I implement virtual directories with node.js and express?

Tags: node.js, express

I want to use the express static server configuration for implementing an static server:

```
app.configure(function() {
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});
```

But I want to map the URL `http://myhost/url1` to directory `C:\dirA\dirB` and `http://myhost/url2` to directory `C:\dirC`

How can it be implemented using express.static?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depending on how many directories you're planning to map this way, you could simply make symlinks for those directories in your `public` folder.

In Windows:

```
mklink /D c:\dirA\dirB public\url1
```

In Linux or OSX:

```
ln -s /dirA/dirB public/url1
```

Then your static assets server should serve from those directories transparently (I've never tested on Windows but I don't see why it wouldn't work).

Alternatively, if you wanted to include some kind of dynamic routing, you could write your own middleware to replace `express.static` which is actually `connect.static` under the hood.  Take a look at [static.js](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/middleware/static.js) in the [connect source](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect) and see how it's implemented, it should be fairly straightforward to write your own variation.

Answer (score 9):

This should work for you:

```
var serveStatic = require( "serve-static" );
app.use('/url1', serveStatic('c:\\dirA\\dirB'));
app.use('/url2', serveStatic('C:\\dirC'));
```

Take a look at the documentation for [app.use()](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.use).

Comment: This is a much simpler and more efficient answer than the accepted one.