# Running Steemconnect on a non-Node.js PHP application

Tags: php, node.js, steemit

I want to be able to use Steemconnect on a web-app I built using PHP/MYSQL/APACHE.

This question (well, the answers) says to do this you should be running Node.js on a subdomain.
[Node.js Server running from a sub folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20077994/node-js-server-running-from-a-sub-folder)

**My question is**, will this work for steemconnect? I can potentially point the callback to the main URL of the app. Would this work?

Or is there a better option to make this work in a PHP app (App uses jQuery and MySQL)?

Note: Steemconnect v2 has been merged (there is only one steemconnect now, not 2 versions) so that is what I am using.

For reference, the app needs to be able to have users sign in to their Steemit account and post comments to their account (blog), that is all.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to simply be able to run packages installed by NPM in your application. There is no real difference to being able to do this and running then in node.js.

I tried [requireJS](https://requirejs.org/), which gave me errors, then [browserify](http://browserify.org/), which worked perfectly.

I hope this helps someone out there!!