# 'Not Found' when routeProvider has id

Tags: angularjs, route-provider

I set my routeProvider as such:

```
routeProvider.when('/', {templateUrl: 'views/index.html', controller: 'IndexCtrl'});
  // $routeProvider.when('/ayat/:surah/:from/:to', {templateUrl: 'views/quran.html', controller: 'AyatCtrl'});
  $routeProvider.when('/:id/:range?', {templateUrl: 'views/quran.html', controller: 'QuranCtrl'});
  $routeProvider.when('/search?', {templateUrl: 'views/search.html', controller: 'SearchCtrl'});
  $routeProvider.when('/about', {templateUrl: 'views/about.html'});
  $routeProvider.when('/contact', {templateUrl: 'views/contact.html'});
  $routeProvider.when('/sorry', {templateUrl: 'views/sorry.html'});
  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
})
```

Whenever I refresh the page, I get 'Not Found'

I didn't run into this problem when previously I had

```
$routeProvider.when('/:extension/:id/:range?', {templateUrl: 'views/quran.html', controller: 'QuranCtrl'});
$locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
```

Comment: will have to set up virtual directory(s) on server using htaccess , web.config or whatever is applicable to your server

Comment: I am using the angular-seed and starting the server with `npm start` no idea where that is or if there is a htaccess

Comment: not hard to find out how in a web search ....`node virtual directory`

Comment: otherwise just run with the hash using `false` for `html5Mode`

Comment: I did the search, came to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10618418/how-can-i-implement-virtual-directories-with-node-js-and-express  No idea how to configure this stuff

Answer (score 0):

the package.json file in the seed project specifies that npm start just runs http-server, which is a node module. It didn't seem to handle html5mode correctly, because in order to handle that, it needs to redirect all requests that aren't for a specific file to your index.html file. You can make a custom node server instead that is pretty simple and just serves the correct files, and allows for refreshing your browser and everything.

[Check out this simple example](http://pastebin.com/ChtCH6tK)

add that at the root of your application (same level as app folder) and then change package.json by changing the start property of scripts to  `"start": "node server.js"`

the method that determines whether or not to route the request to index.html or not is this one

```
function isSpecificFile(path){
  var regex = /^\/(bower_components|css|img|js|partials)\/.*/;
  return regex.test(path);
}
```

If you have a request like `localhost:8000/foo`, that needs to be done in angular, so index.html will be loaded and angular will load the specific files with requests of the form '/js/controllers/foo_ctrl.js', which the server won't route to index.html.

I would look for a more robust solution for anything production like though.